# how to initialize objects of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

i have an array of 10 objects and i would like to  initialize them for the array.

```
private Flight[] flight = new Flight[10];

flight[0] = new Flight("AA101", "Boston", "Sacremento", 421.33, 22, 6);
flight[1] = new Flight("AA102", "Lincolin", Jacksonville, 612.08, 22 6);
flight[2] = new Flight("AA103", "Rochester", "Columbia", 510.83, 22, 6);
flight[3] = new Flight("AA104", "Boise", "Aspen", 411.12, 22, 6);
flight[4] = new Flight("AA105", "Fort Collins", "Louiseville", 654.22, 22, 6);
flight{5} = new Flight("AA106", "Seattle", "Dallas" 326.14, 22, 6);
flight{6} = new Flight("AA107", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", 974.22, 22, 6);
flight[7] = new Flight("AA108", "Cheyenne", "Louiseville", 521.43 , 22, 6);
flight[8] = new Flight("AA109", "Louiseville", "Buffalo", 452.21, 22, 6);
flight[9] = new Flight("AA100", "Anchorage" , "Tampa", 874.72, 22, 6);
```

but i get tons of errors such as:

> ReservationGUI.java:31: error: ']' expected
>
> ReservationGUI.java:31: error: illegal start of type
>
> ReservationGUI.java:31: error: ';' expected
>
> ReservationGUI.java:31: error:  expected

there are 100 of them.

Comment: `Jacksonville` should have quotes around it, unless it references a variable somewhere

Comment: move all these these lines (except the first one) inside some method (or constructor)

Comment: Eran could you elaborate on our method i don't like to alter my code unless i fully understand why i am doing it a certain way

Comment: @Josh.O You need an enclosing class and an enclosing method. Otherwise, this would not be legal in Java. One remark on your code: please write the array-brackets after the type, not the name: `Flight[] flights;`. I suspect your way of writing it is only there for the habit of C[++] programmers.

Answer (score 0):

use square brackets instead of curly brackets for 5 and 6 elements

Answer (score 0):

You have many typos, and all programming languages are very unforgiving about typos.

Another approach:

```
private Flight[] flight = new Flight[] {
  new Flight("AA101", "Boston", "Sacremento", 421.33, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA102", "Lincolin", "Jacksonville", 612.08, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA103", "Rochester", "Columbia", 510.83, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA104", "Boise", "Aspen", 411.12, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA105", "Fort Collins", "Louiseville", 654.22, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA106", "Seattle", "Dallas", 326.14, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA107", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", 974.22, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA108", "Cheyenne", "Louiseville", 521.43, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA109", "Louiseville", "Buffalo", 452.21, 22, 6),
  new Flight("AA100", "Anchorage" , "Tampa", 874.72, 22, 6)
};
```